# Apt-get or aptitude is running on my laptop and doesn´t let my update my software, how do I turn it of?

Tags: 12.04, apt, updates

When I try to update the software on my laptop it says I can´t update everything at the same time but I can upgrade gradually, but then a window pops up and says that "apt-get or aptitude" currently is running and I have to turn it of to be able to update the software but I can´t figure out how to turn it of.

Answer (score 1):

Try to restart your computer (use `sudo reboot` in a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal)). After restarts the first thing you should do is to open a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) and run next commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

These will update your software. Don't install/unsinstall nothing in this time using another program.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `ps -A` in your terminal and look for apt-get or aptitude in the list of running processes. Note the pid apt-get/aptitude and run `kill 99999` replacing "99999" with the appropriate pid. This should kill the process if it is running.

If it does not, try running it with sudo.